# zip unzip attachments in wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, uploads, media-library

my client using easy digital download plugin for sell their photos. They upload a zip file that contain many photos and sell this zip file. My need is to extract this zip file and display the images in it in a page.So i need to get all the images from this zip . I need to do some custom work on it. 
Is there any method to unzip this files via code ? please help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress provides a function called [`unzip_file()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unzip_file)-- easily found by typing "wordpress unzip" into Google. There is sample code in the Codex:

```
WP_Filesystem();
$destination = wp_upload_dir();
$destination_path = $destination['path'];
$unzipfile = unzip_file( $destination_path.'/filename.zip', $destination_path);

if ( $unzipfile ) {
  echo 'Successfully unzipped the file!';       
} else {
  echo 'There was an error unzipping the file.';       
}
```

I have no idea what "custom work" you need to do.

Comment: .many thanks s_ha_dum . I need to display this images with some watermark on it, in single product page. Did you know is there any method to watermark on this unziped images . ?. And really thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @ronr better ask another question. But please note, read the [FAQ] first, questions not specific to WordPress are off-topic here in WPSE.